# Assert in Try..Catch block is caught

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, assert

Just came across some interesting behavior - `Assert` being caught by `Catch` block.

```
List<Decimal> consArray = new List<decimal>();
try
{
    Decimal d;
    Assert.IsTrue(Decimal.TryParse(item.Value, out d));
    consArray.Add(d);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
     Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Assert throws `AssertFailedException` and its caught by `catch`. Always thought that if `Assert` fails then test is failed and consecutive execution is aborted. But in that case - test moves along. If nothing wrong happens later - I get **green** test! In theory - is it right behavior?

Edited: I understand that maybe it is .NET restriction and how asserts are made in MsTest. Assert throws exception. Since `catch` - catches everything it catches assert exception. But is it right in theory or MsTest specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NUnit` will do the exact same thing. As should any other test framework I think, but I only know `MStest` and `NUnit` in C#.

I'd expect that your test code would not contain `Decimal.TryParse`, but your business logic would do that, which you'd test with an object and a method call.

Something like:

```
var sut = new Sut();
var d = sut.DoSomethingThatReturnsTheDecimal(item.Value);

Assert.AreEqual(0.123, d, string.Format("passed value can not be parsed to decimal ({0})", item.Value);
```

In order to stay a bit closer to your implementation:

```
List<Decimal> consArray = new List<decimal>();

Decimal d = Decimal.MinValue;

// You don't need to try-catch a Decimal.TryParse
// Decimal.TryParse(item.Value, out d));

try
{
    d = Decimal.Parse(item.Value)
}
catch
{
    // Handle exception
}

Assert.AreEqual(0.123, d);

// Does the list add anything at all? In this sample it seems a bit redundant
consArray.Add(d);
```

Anyway, to answer your question. The try-catch is supposed to catch your `AssertFailedException`.

PS: Catching the `AsserFailedException` and re-throwing it will also work, but it feels a bit strange to me. I'd strive to leave the `Assert`s outside any `try-catch` blocks. But that might be just my opinion which you didn't ask for :).

Comment: It was spike - logic will be moved to method. Anyway, note to myself - don't use try..catch in MsTest. Still interesting how is it going in other test frameworks - Java, PHP.

Comment: Ah sorry thought you meant c# frameworks. Java is a while ago but pretty sure it does the same. Tip: update question with info that java, PHP, etc is what interests you. Gl with your answer and happy coding :)

Answer (score 6):

As already answered, this is correct behavior. You can change your code to get *Your* expected behavior by catching the AssertFailedException and re-throwing it.

```
        List<Decimal> consArray = new List<decimal>();
        try
        {
            Decimal d;
            Assert.IsTrue(Decimal.TryParse(item.Value, out d));
            consArray.Add(d);
        }
        catch (AssertFailedException)
        {
            throw;
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working as expected. When an `Assert` fails it throws an [AssertFailedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assertfailedexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which 
inherits from [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So you can add a `try-catch` and catch it.

In your case, add a `throw` at the end of the `catch` and re-throw the exception.

Comment: Yes I know that it works since Assert throws exception and catch catches it. Just want to know is it right in TDD theory? Is assert fails than test should be red - isn't it? Is it MSTest specific behavior? What about other test frameworks?

Comment: @nikita: This has nothing to do with TDD nor MsTest. `Assert` is not any kind of special member - it's just a **class** like any other. All frameworks work in exactly the same way. On a sidenote, you shouldn't really be using `try-catch` nor `Console.WriteLine` in your **unit** test.

Comment: Because your test framework will output to console anyway. A failing test will give stacktrace in cmd or IDE. Further more asserts allow additional text as i tried to picture in my example in my answer