# xunit core in try catch block is not working right

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, xunit

[Duplicated][Assert in Try..Catch block is caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889310/assert-in-try-catch-block-is-caught)

When I using Xunit Core in NetCore1.1 in VS2017 as folllow:

[image]

```
     try
        {
            Assert.True(1<0," server is false");//vs2017 show green(test through)

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            while (e != null)
            {
                _outputHelper.WriteLine(e.Message);
                e = e.InnerException;
            }
        }

        Assert.True(1 < 0, "current value is false");// vs2017 show red(test failed
```

The result is that the icon is green, not red when the first `Assert.True` it not right(failed).like that  as follow:

[image]

if add second  `Assert.True` it's red;

[image])

It is very odd, Is that right? I think that's a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug.

All unit test frameworks, including xUnit.net, use exceptions for failing assertions. You have blindly caught and swallowed all exceptions; this would include the exception for the failed assertion.

It's also really not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this code. Maybe this was a simplification for the purposes of illustration...?

Comment: Hi @Brad Wilson, Thanks for your reply? I want to test EF Demo function, [here](https://github.com/huoxudong125/HQF.Tutorials.EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/Tests/HQF.Tutorials.EntityFrameworkCore.XUnitTest/UnitTest1.cs) is the full demo code. Is there a good pattern to implement?

Comment: Just don't catch. Any exceptions that are thrown will be shown as failures. You can leave the try/finally for the resource cleanup, just without the catch.